# Determine the probability that a randomly selected integer is divisible by one of several integers.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If you choose an element $x$ uniformly at random from the set $\{1,2,\dots,100\}$, what is the probability that $x$ is divisible by $4$ or $5$?

Can someone explain why the answer is $2/5$ please, thanks.

Comment: Because there are $40$ elements in that set that are divisible by $4$ or $5$ (you have $\{4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, ...\}$) and the set itself has $100$ elements.

Comment: o ic, maybe is should go to sleep lol I cant think anymore. Thank you!

Comment: @mvitagames You can calculate it like this: 25 numbers can be divided by 4 (100/4). And 20 numbers can be divided by 5 (100/5). You can sum this values. Now you have counted twice the numbers, which can be divided by 4 and 5. Just subtract 5 (20,40,60,80,100). Have a good sleep.

Comment: Please, use a meaningful title to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{1,2, \dots ,100\}$, $A=\{x \in S: 4|x\}$, $B=\{x \in S: 5|x\}$, $A \cap B=\{x \in S: 20|x\}$. Then $|A|=25$, $|B|=20$ and $|A \cap B|=5$. Using the inclusion-exclusion formula
$$|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|=25+20-5=40$$
Since $|S|=100$ that gives $p=40/100=2/5$.